# How to keep the full URL when doing a redirect in PHP to Heroku?

Tags: php, redirect, heroku

Maybe I'm not using the right technique for the task (and if you have any suggestion for what I'm trying to achieve, that would be welcome too).

I have an app on Heroku at `http://some-app.herokuapp.com`. I own the domain `some-app.com` and it is currently pointed to a shared host (where I receive emails `@some-app.com` and store static files in `http://assets.some-app.com`).

In order to redirect the domain to the app on Heroku, I added a new CNAME on my shared hosting for `www.some-app.com` that redirects to `http://some-app.herokuapp.com`. That works well.

Now, if I navigate to `http://some-app.com`, I don't get redirected (which is normal, the 'naked' domain name points to my shared hosting). So, on my shared host, within `some-app.com/public_html/` I added the following `index.php` file:

```
<?php 
header("Location: http://www.some-app.com");
```

That works well, `http://some-app.com` redirects to `http://www.some-app.com` which in turns, through the CNAME correctly opens `http://some-app.herokuapp.com`, keeping `www.some-app.com` in the address bar of the browser.

Where I am stuck is this: although `http://www.some-app.com/some-dir/` works well, `http://some-app.com/some-dir` doesn't redirect. Instead, I get a 404.

How to handle this properly while keeping my emails and static files on the shared hosting (cpanel based, if that helps).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I found the most elegant way to do this. Place a `.htaccess` file at the root of `public_html` with the following content:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```